# NSVIew Custom view is not resizing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

I am newbie in Mac programming, using all standard approach I put a custom view inside a window controller. When I try to resize a window by mouse, inner content, i.e. custom view is not getting resized.

Can anyone tell me what is missing in my code? So far I have done following:

1. Setting AutoResize subview in
   all view inside the window
2. Set AutoResizeMask to Width and
   height

When I checked using NSLog in reference code where resize is happening, then I came to know for my code DrawRect for a view is not getting called. I suspect this might be the issue, but why this is not getting I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Does the window's contentView have `autoresizesSubviews` set to `YES`?

Comment: HI, layout is like that, Window Controller has its own content view, inside content view, i have two custom view, now on resizing its coming to draw of the custom view but getting the same frame-rect, should i set the setFrame in the Window controller to get the custom view resized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your code like this

```
[yourCustomView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];
```